# Use std::string as datamember in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++, stdstring

I want to use a C++ string object in my Objective-C code instead of a NSString so I don't need to covert it (I need the std::string more often) and I tried doing it like this:

```
using namespace std;

@interface InstrumentGridViewController : UIViewController {   
string* trackName; // also tried using std::string, didn't work
@property (nonatomic, assign) string* trackName;
}
```

I'm getting errors though, both the `string* trackName;` statement and the `@property` line give me `Expected specifier-qualifier-list 'string'`.

**EDIT:** I forgot to add `#include <string>` but adding this gives me the error `String: no such file or directory`

Comment: Have you #include'd <string>?

Comment: I have now, still giving me errors, I've updated my question.

Comment: Do you have your file named as `.mm`?

Comment: This is a header file, is that necessary for `.h` files? I've been able to use my own C++ classes fine without changing the extension.

Comment: @Sled never put C++ objects in a objective-c header, it just breaks things for people who come along in the future.

Comment: Don't really have any other options though, I need a string datamember..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What matters is the source files this header file is included by. If this header file is included in a normal Objective-C source file (.m extension) the compiler will choke as you described. If you check the errors carefully in Xcode you can see exactly which source file or files this header file failed to compile in.

This is why it is often suggested never to use C++ objects in header files intended to be consumed by Objective C code. C++ in header files tends to bleed all over your code base and force you to compile everything was Objective C++ (.mm extension). Note that with the modern runtime and class extensions it is very easy to work around this. Just move your:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) string* trackName;
```

to a class extension in your InstrumentGridViewController.mm file and remove the `trackName` ivar declaration that is not needed in the modern runtime. Then your header is Objective C clean and can be included by the rest of your code. Rob Napier has more discussion on this in [Wrapping C++ Final Edition](http://robnapier.net/blog/wrapping-cppfinal-edition-759).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile everything as Obj-c++ and don't want to go through the tiresome process of changing all your file extensions, just provide the `-x objective-c++` flag to the compiler (project settings -> other c flags) and link with the stdlibc++. That way you can use c++ all other your code without worrying